# CoordinatorLayout not working in Android Studio 2.1.2?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-studio-2.1

My Android Studio is unable to find the `CoordinatorLayout` class.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

It says:

> The following classes could not be found: -android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.musical_box.musicbox.MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/player_Control_container">
</FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but i have tried most of the solutions, and none worked for me. One thing I noticed that Android Studio is not suggesting `CoordinatorLayout` while writing code. I am guessing that there are some missing libraries. Here is the code for my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.musical_box.musicbox"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

I have build tools 24.0.0 installed on my system. Can anyone help as I am unable to figure out the problem and new to Android dev.
 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

to your gradle file. It should work. Its part of design library. So you need to add this one to access `CoordinatorLayout`.